# java code to do path search from one node to another for a large graph(600X600) in milli secs

Tags: java, shortest-path

I have a large graph with agents moving from one point to another. the problem is when i want to determine the path between two nodes that are close, the time taken is small. what algorithm can i use to determine the the path between say a node at coordinat 1,1 and a node at coordinate 599,599 for a coordinate system with 600/600 width and height.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful if you [added](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29432145/edit) relevant code and additional information to your question, such as what you've tried/thought about so far, how you store the graph (adjacency list vs matrix) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information about the constraints of your specific task, I'd recommend you to have a look at  the [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Do you have any java code sample or  to help make things easier.